# ValueError: Supply a 'c' kwarg or a 'color' kwarg but not both; they differ but their functionalities overlap

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I tried to run one example in the book of Python Data Science Essential. But, it appeared errors when I ran it. Actually, I just began learning the python. So, I felt that it is hard to fix those errors. Please help me.
Here is code:

```
In:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
In: colors = list()
In: palette = {0: "red", 1: "green", 2: "blue"}
In:
for c in np.nditer(iris.target): colors.append(palette[int(c)])
    # using the palette dictionary, we convert
    # each numeric class into a color string
In: dataframe = pd.DataFrame(iris.data,
columns=iris.feature_names)
In: scatterplot = pd.scatter_matrix(dataframe, alpha=0.3,
figsize=(10, 10), diagonal='hist', color=colors, marker='o',
grid=True)
```

Here is errors:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 scatterplot = pd.scatter_matrix(dataframe, alpha=0.3,
>   ----> 2 figsize=(10, 10), diagonal='hist', color=colors, marker='o',grid=True)
>
> /Users/leeivan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py
>   in scatter_matrix(frame, alpha, figsize, ax, grid, diagonal, marker,
>   density_kwds, hist_kwds, range_padding, **kwds)
>       378 
>       379                 ax.scatter(df[b][common], df[a][common],
>   --> 380                            marker=marker, alpha=alpha, **kwds)
>       381 
>       382                 ax.set_xlim(boundaries_list[j])
>
> /Users/leeivan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.pyc
>   in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)    1817
>   warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.**name**),    1818
>   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
>   -> 1819             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)    1820         pre_doc = inner.**doc**    1821         if pre_doc is None:
>
> /Users/leeivan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.pyc
>   in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha,
>   linewidths, verts, edgecolors, **kwargs)    3787
>   facecolors = co    3788             if c is not None:
>   -> 3789                 raise ValueError("Supply a 'c' kwarg or a 'color' kwarg"    3790                                  " but not
>   both; they differ but"    3791                                  "
>   their functionalities overlap.")
>
> ValueError: Supply a 'c' kwarg or a 'color' kwarg but not both; they
>   differ but their functionalities overlap.

Comment: If you think appropriate, having provided both a resolution and an explanation to the problem, please tick the answer as addressing the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tested the code below in jupyter and python 3.5 and it works.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
%matplotlib inline

iris = load_iris()
colors = list()
palette = {0: "red", 1: "green", 2: "blue"}

for c in np.nditer(iris.target): colors.append(palette[int(c)])
    # using the palette dictionary, we convert
    # each numeric class into a color string
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(iris.data,
columns=iris.feature_names)
scatterplot = pd.scatter_matrix(dataframe, alpha=0.3,
figsize=(10, 10), diagonal='hist', c=colors, marker='o', grid=True)
```

Clearly the parameter `color` is generating the error, while `c` is working. 
On the other hand it could be a bug in matplotlib.

This is what I found, looking at the pandas function:

```
def scatter_matrix(frame, alpha=0.5, figsize=None, ax=None, grid=False,
                   diagonal='hist', marker='.', density_kwds=None,
                   hist_kwds=None, range_padding=0.05, **kwds):
    """
    Draw a matrix of scatter plots.
    Parameters
    ----------
    frame : DataFrame
    alpha : float, optional
        amount of transparency applied
    figsize : (float,float), optional
        a tuple (width, height) in inches
    ax : Matplotlib axis object, optional
    grid : bool, optional
        setting this to True will show the grid
    diagonal : {'hist', 'kde'}
        pick between 'kde' and 'hist' for
        either Kernel Density Estimation or Histogram
        plot in the diagonal
    marker : str, optional
        Matplotlib marker type, default '.'
    hist_kwds : other plotting keyword arguments
        To be passed to hist function
    density_kwds : other plotting keyword arguments
        To be passed to kernel density estimate plot
    range_padding : float, optional
        relative extension of axis range in x and y
        with respect to (x_max - x_min) or (y_max - y_min),
        default 0.05
    kwds : other plotting keyword arguments
        To be passed to scatter function
```

So it appears that `colors` or `c` are passed to the `scatter` function in `matplotlib` as one of the `**kwds` in the function call.

This is the scatter function:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(x, y, s=20, c=None, marker='o', cmap=None, norm=None, vmin=None, vmax=None, alpha=None, linewidths=None, verts=None, edgecolors=None, hold=None, data=None, **kwargs)
```

Here the parameter is `c` and not `color`, but in other parts `color` is listed as an alternative to `c` (as you would expect).

I posted an issue on [matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7603).  I will keep you informed.

**NEWS as of 11/12/2016**

After a bit of discussions, the bug has been accepted by pandas and scheduled for fixing in the next major release. See [here on github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14855)

Basically when `c` is specified, `c` is sent to the `scatter` function in matplotlib.  When `color` is specified, both `c` and `color` are sent, confusing matplotlib.

For the time been, as suggested, use `c` instead of `color`

Answer (score -4):

So I'm on my phone at the moment and can't trace it through but here is what I can tell you. A **kwarg** is when you pass a key word argument to a function.

```
scatterplot = pd.scatter_matrix(dataframe, alpha=0.3,figsize=(10, 10),diagonal='hist',color=colors, marker='o',grid=True)
```

Right there **color=colors** is a keyword argument. Now somewhere in your function calls it looks like **c** becomes a keyword argument. I don't see how you can change that but you could get rid of your **color** Kwarg and that might fix things for now. Otherwise you need to look at that those functions in your stack trace and find out when **c** is becoming a kwarg

Comment: When I deleted **color=colors**, the example surely ran without  mistakes. But, I hope represent different classes with different colors. So, I need to continue to find out reasons.  Thank you.